# CGRectMake Symbol not Found

Tags: macos, core-graphics, core-foundation, jsctypes

I'm trying to declare some CoreGraphics functions, specificially `CGRectMake` and it keeps telling me symbol not found.

The docs say I need to import CoreGraphics: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake

The path to my CoreGraphics is `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation`; how can I find the right library for this function? I am doing this from ctypes.

By the way, from reading the docs it seems to just memset a CGRect and populate its width, height, x, and y is this true? (in which case I won't need to bother declaring it, it's so simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I couldn't export the function so the solution I had to use was define the function myself, i guess that it was just returning a rect with fields populated and it worked :)

```
    CGRectMake: function() {
        /* https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake
         *  CGRect CGRectMake (
         *    CGFloat x,
         *    CGFloat y,
         *    CGFloat width,
         *    CGFloat height
         * ); 
         */
         /******* does not work
        return lib('CoreGraphics').declare('CGRectMake', self.TYPE.ABI,
            self.TYPE.CGRect,   // return
            self.TYPE.CGFloat,  // x
            self.TYPE.CGFloat,  // y
            self.TYPE.CGFloat,  // width
            self.TYPE.CGFloat   // height
        );
        */
        return function(x, y, width, height) {
            return self.TYPE.CGRect(
                self.TYPE.CGPoint(x, y),
                self.TYPE.CGSize(width, height)
            );
        };
    }
```

Comment: This is the necessary approach. `CGRectMake()` is inlined. It is not exported by the CoreGraphics framework (or any other). The compiler will usually just replace the call with the direct setting of the `CGRect` fields. Under certain circumstances, the function will exist as a separate entity but will be built into the *calling* code (e.g. an app executable).

Comment: Btw @KenThomases is there anywhere like online or could you show me how on mac to open it up and see the contents of CGRectMake inline function?

Comment: You can look in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.*.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGGeometry.h. In general, identify the framework where a symbol is declared and search its header.

Comment: That @KenThomases is a monster of knowledge. :)

Comment: Dude totaly @uchuugaka best part is he shares it so freely he is amazing and very patient.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to add the CoreGraphics Framework then:

```
1. Select Target
2. Build Phases
3. Link Binary With Libraries
4. +
5. CoreGraphics.framework
6. Add
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ILI but I am doing this from ctypes so I ned to us the full path, can you please share with me the path so I can try in ctypes.

Comment: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework`, or here: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/CoreGraphics.framework`

Comment: Thank you very much I'm trying it now, can you please show me how to get that,I'm not able to install Xcode on my system due to security :( edit: It didn't work :( the library won't open :( I tried `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics` and the library opened but it said symbol not found :(

Comment: Thanks very much I'm downloading now :) What should I do with downloaded file?

Comment: Interesting... is `CGRect` the only symbol not found?

Comment: Well I don't use all the functionalities just some, there are like 15 other functions I use though all of them except `CGRectMake` are found :( https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/mac-troubleshooting/modules/ostypes_mac.jsm#L315

Comment: You should be able to take the downloaded framework and link it like: `let CoreGraphics = ctypes.open("/path/to/downloaded/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics");` - or try the one in the `/System/Library/Frameworks` - depends on how you're using it perhaps. What does the import statement you are using look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77472/discussion-between-lll-and-noitidart).

Answer (score 1):

You either have a missing import or a big somewhere else that is preventing the compiler from seeing this in context, or a typo.

That said CGRect and NSRect are identical on the last few OS X releases. You only NEED to use CGRect when building code that will also be compiled for iOS.

Comment: I use `CGRect` all the time on `OS X`; I'm doubting it's only for `iOS`.

Comment: Indeed. Historically CGRect and NSRect were not the same thing and were  not conveniently swappable. My point is  most OS X APIs still use NSRect and other NS prefixed C constructs even when a CG version exists. If building cross platform code, you need to use CGRect or you have to do silly conditional macros based on target platform because other Apple platforms do not know NSRect.

Comment: CGRect was originally only for Core Graphics C API which interestingly is MUCH younger than NSRect, which dates back to its prefix' namesake NeXT. (back when there was no Core Graphics API, but rather a Display PostScript API)

Comment: Thanks @uchuugaka for such an awesome history lesson and it got me thinking of my code is OSX 10.6+ able, because thats my goal to support 10.6+.